# How should I properly stop a Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am making a simple GUI for a video capture application using customtkinter and opencv. The code below is the creation and start of the thread which is responsible for executing the video capture function. This code is inside the initialization of my application class:

```
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
       ...
       self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
       self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.videoLoop, args=())
       self.thread.start()
       ...
```

the function for the actual video capturing is:

```
def videoLoop(self):
    while True:
        if self.stopEvent.is_set() == True:
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        img = cv2.rectangle(frame, (380, 80), (1540,950), (0,0,255),2)
        #add vertical line
        img2 = cv2.line(img, (960, 85), (960,945), (0,255,0),1)
        #add horizontal line
        img3 = cv2.line(img2, (400, 515), (1520,515), (0,255,0),1)
        #get frame rate
        fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        #add frame rate text
        disp_frame = cv2.putText(img3, "FPS: "+ str(fps), (0, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (100, 255, 0), 2)
        conv_img = cv2.cvtColor(disp_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        conv_img = Image.fromarray(conv_img)
        conv_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=conv_img)
        self.videoframe.create_image(500,500,image=conv_img,anchor="s")
        self.videoframe.image = conv_img
```

upon exiting the application, the on_closing is executed for the clean-up:

```
def on_closing(self):
    self.stopEvent.set()
    self.destroy()
```

The issue with this one is that when I try to exit the app, the thread that handles the video capturing seems to not terminate properly as I cannot interact with my VSCode terminal requiring me to run a new instance of the terminal before I can run my application again. Is there a specific way to stop the thread?

Comment: Also it looks like you are calling `PhotoImage` and `.create_image` from another thread - don't do that, it is possible to make python crash without an error traceback. `tkinter` doesn't play nice when you call its methods from other threads. Also if you don't have any `cv2` windows open, why are you using `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`?

Comment: I removed `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` as it was unnecessary for my end. I also commented out `conv_img = cv2.cvtColor(disp_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            conv_img = Image.fromarray(conv_img)
            conv_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=conv_img)
            self.videoframe.create_image(500,500,image=conv_img,anchor="s")
            self.videoframe.image = conv_img` which made my app exit properly. How do I get a workaround for this part to not cause improper termination?

Comment: You can do the `opencv` stuff in the 2nd thread, but you should only call `tkinter` methods (like `PhotoImage`, `.create_image`) from the thread where you created the `tk.Tk`. Also I noticed that you only keep adding images to the canvas without removing any of them - I don't know if that will cause you trouble in the future.

Comment: With Python 3 it *is* possible to call `tkinter` methods from threads other than the main thread, with some restrictions. First, `tkinter` must be built with threading support. This is the case with the builds from python.org, IIRC. But it might not be on operating systems that have their own builds. Second, the `mainloop` should run on the main thread.

Comment: @RolandSmith That isn't entirely true - [example](https://pastebin.com/wF5Fn19a). The garbage collector can sometimes delete `tkinter` objects from threads which can cause python to crash - without an error.

Comment: @TheLizzard Hmm, that looks like a bit of a contrived example to me. It is easily fixed by moving `root` to the global scope. In practice I've had no issues so far calling `tkinter` methods from secondary threads.

Comment: @RolandSmith It is there just to prove that `tkinter` and threads is dangerous to the point where you shouldn't access (or be able to access) `tkinter` objects from other threads. Even if the 2 restrictions that you pointed out are followed, I can still make `python` crash. Also in my example the problem is that `function` has access to `root`.

Comment: @TheLizzard According to [comments](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c#L225) in the source for _tkinter: "Invoking commands from other threads is possible".

Comment: @RolandSmith Well [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83274) is the issue in `cpython` repo on GitHub. Also if you look `tkinter/_init__.py`, you will see a lot of commented debug lines that were never updated from python 2. `tkinter` is so old that no one wants to touch it as it will break existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are perceiving a runtime issue. When this gets executed:

```
def on_closing(self):
    self.stopEvent.set()
    self.destroy()
```

Is it possible that self got detroyed before the other thread had a chance to properly finish?

In that case do not destroy the object immediately. Wait for a signal from the background thread that it has stopped processing, then run destroy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the thread issue. Instead of initializing and starting the thread inside the App class, I created it inside the top-level code which now looks like this (btw, I renamed the `videoLoop` function into `thread_loop:`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=app.thread_loop,args=())
    thread.start()
    app.mainloop()
    thread.join()
```

and my on_closing function

```
def on_closing(self):
    cap.release()
    self.destroy()
```

I'm not sure if this is best solution but the thread now terminates properly